# Azure AD Administrative data API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

Is there a way/endpoint through which I can pull some administrative data using graph API like,

App name (I've got this one - /beta/applications)

Does it use Single Sign On?

Does it require users to enroll for 2FA, etc

SAML configuration

Conditional Access

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no such API about the info about SSO, MFA, SAML configuration and conditional access.

And there are some common endpoints that Azure AD.

OpenId Connect Metadata:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration

Federation metadata

https://login.microsoftonline.com//FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml

More detail about the protocols Azure AD supports, you can refer the link below:

[Azure Active Directory Authentication Protocols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-protocols)

And if you have any idea or feedback about Azure AD, you can try to submit it through [this link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory).